# Mercurial - hg bisect - view simple list of contributing changesets

Tags: mercurial

I'm looking to view all the changesets that have been tested by an hg bisect.

I want them in a simple, easy to read format like:

```
2391928719e - good
7321374343e - good
3232738237e - bad
4873487473e - bad
39732197132 - bad
39732197132 - bad
```

I know about hg log -r bisect(range), but I don't think that gives me the status?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bisect(range)` just gives you the revisions that participated, yes. Your problem is with the *output*, not with the revset, so look at `hg help template` instead to get output options.

There you'll find:

```
$ hg help template | grep ' bisect '
    bisect        String. The commit bisection status.
```

Use that in a `-T` template:

```
hg log -r 'bisect(range)' -T '{node|short} - {bisect}\n'
```

This then gives you your list of nodes participating, with their status; one of `good`, `bad`, `untested`, `ignored` or `skipped`.

There is even a built-in template for this, named `bisect`; this is just the default template with a `bisect: {bisect}` line added:

```
hg log -r 'bisect(range)' -T bisect
```

There's also a `shortbisect` filter; it'll return a single letter for a given bisection status rather than the full text. This is helpful in a `-G` graph, set the `ui.graphnodetemplate` option to `{bisect|shortbisect}` to have the node 'icon' be the status:

```
hg log -r 'bisect(range)' -G \
   --config "ui.graphnodetemplate={bisect|shortbisect}"
   -T compact
```

which produces something like

```
G  1011   2391928719e   2017-09-21 15:58 +0530   author
|    first line of commit message
|
G  1010   7321374343e   2017-09-21 15:58 +0530   author
|    first line of commit message
|
B  1009   3232738237e   2017-09-21 15:58 +0530   author
|    first line of commit message
|
B  1008   4873487473e   2017-09-21 15:58 +0530   author
|    first line of commit message
|
B  1007   39732197132   2017-09-21 15:58 +0530   author
|    first line of commit message
|
B  1006   39732197132   2017-09-21 15:58 +0530   author
|    first line of commit message
~
```